# find value difference in varchar column update in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can we find just the difference on updated column value for example if we have a column named path and it has value '/home/rafiq/Desktop', now if path is updated to '/home/user/Desktop', i just need to get 'user' as the difference value. please help if there is any function or any logic to get just the difference string in OLD and NEW values.

path column before update

```
path
/home/user/Desktop
```

path column after update

```
path
/home/admin/vm/Desktop
```

here i need to get 'admin/vm' to update other column values in the row using trigger, any help will be appreciated.

What can change:

1. /home and /Desktop are the beginning and ending for any path so only path in between can change. Only difference in OLD and NEW path should be reported even if there more common folders. If we update '/home/A/B/Desktop' with '/home/A/C/Desktop' only 'C' should be reported.
2. I only care about whole parts between / changing. i.e. if /home/admin/blah changed to /home/administration/blah, output should be 'administration'
   I am using postgres 9.3 hope this is clear now.

Comment: this is not an easy problem, and not even well defined. For example, what output do you expect if you have `/home/animal/Desktop` before and `/home/admin/Desktop`? Are the differences based on the character position (doesn't seem so) or what else?

Comment: difference based on common beginning and endings (not fixed though), '/home/' and '/Desktop' in your case and output should be 'admin', hope thats clear

Comment: in this case, you should write a custom comparison function

Comment: yes, i just need help to do so, looking for hints from those who might have tried something similar

Comment: Are you tried in trigger

Comment: Actually, your definition is not clear at all. Before anybody starts writing a function, the definition should be crystal clear. What *can* change? And what should be reported in each case? Add a list of possible cases if it's hard to describe. Also add the table definition (what you get with `\d tbl`in `psql`) and your version of Postgres.

Comment: @SATSON yes I am trying in trigger to update based on the difference

Comment: Do you only care about whole parts between `/` changing? i.e. if `/home/admin/blah` changed to `/home/admiraration/blah`, what's the output? `admi`? `('admi','n')` ? `admiration`? Something else? You need to *properly define the problem*.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, Craig Ringer I have updated the description, hope it is clear

Comment: @RAFIQ: No, it's not. `If we update '/home/A/B/Desktop' with '/home/A/C/Desktop' only 'C' should be reported.` So what do we report for '/home/A/B/Desktop' -> '/home/C/Desktop'? Or '/home/A/Desktop' -> '/home/A/C/Desktop'? '/home/A/B/C/Desktop' -> '/home/A/X/B/X/C/Desktop'?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter In your case '/home/A/B/Desktop' -> '/hom/C/Desktop'? Output: 'C', '/home/A/Desktop' -> '/home/A/C/Desktop'? Output: 'A/C', '/home/A/B/C/Desktop' -> '/home/A/X/B/X/C/Desktop' Output: 'X/B/X'. we need to filter just the part of the new path that has replaced part of the old path that is uncommon between old and new complete paths. Remember /home and /desktop are common to all paths so the largest change we report is entire sub path between these two.

Comment: @RAFIQ did you check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This: Hope Its Helpful

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_trg_t()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$ 

declare
 res varchar[];
 num int;
 ol record;
 ne record;
 i int=0;
 xstr text;

 begin

 for xold in select unnest(string_to_array(new.path,'/')) as gg Loop
  num=0;

  if xold.gg is not null then

  for xnew in select unnest(string_to_array(old.path,'/')) as rr loop

   if num=0 and xold.gg=xnew.rr then num=1; end if;

  end loop;

 if num=0 then
  res[i]=ol.gg;
  i=i+1;
  end if;
end if;

end loop;

 select array_to_string(res,'/') into xstr;

raise notice ' %', xstr;

 return xstr;
 end; 
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```